# Create various tables from some Model with Flask-Sqlalchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

From the docs, I can see how to create the Models necessary to later create the Tables.

What I want is to create various tables, each with different `__tablename__` att., but all of them with the same properties, thus the need for just one Model class which will serve as a model for all the tables.

I looked into the db.metadata option, but the docs state that it is designed for read-only purpose.

EDIT1:

To create a table from a model, I create

```py
class Sample(db.Model):
    //code here
```

then to create the table from the model, a script is run which executes

```py
manage.py migrate
manage.py update
```

What would be the correct way to create the mentioned tables on runtime?

EDIT2:

Having found [a question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22567092/multiple-identical-tables-in-flask-sqlalchemy) similar to mine, I tried the accepted answer, which proposes the use of `type` to create the tables, but that doesn't seem to work as expected.

In my `app/my_model.py` file I have the model which at first inherited from db.Model, but later removed that following the example in the mentioned question. In my `app/routes.py`, when I run `type(name.title(), (MyModel, db.Model), { '__tablename__' : name })` and print the given object, I get `<class 'app.routes.name'>`, as opposed to the expected `<class 'flask_sqlalchemy.Name'>`.

I posted a separate question because the doubt is broader than what the existing question covers, I think.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You might be interested in [mixins](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/extensions/declarative/mixins.html).

Comment: Thanks, @IljaEverilä, I'll check it out!

Comment: @IljaEverilä From what I see, this serves the purpose to reuse a base Model, and then define inherit from it in later classes' definition. This wouldn't serve the purpose to create the tables on runtime. Or am I missing something? Sorry, I updated the question later :^|

Comment: Is your only concern with the `__repr__` of the class? The `__repr__` you're seeing is a function of the module that the type is defined in, and it's `__qualname__` attrib. Unless you override `__repr__` in `MyModel`, or pass a custom `model_class` to `SQLAlchemy()` that overrides the standard `__repr__`, or actually define the classes inside `flask_sqlalchemy.__init__.py`, then then they won't print like `<class 'flask_sqlalchemy.some_name>'. Usually the string representation of a class isn't what you'd use to gauge it usefulness though, so maybe I've misunderstood.

Comment: @SuperShoot No, my concern is not about the `__repr__`. I checked if the table was created; since it wasn't, I wanted to see what the `type` line actually returned, having as a point of comparison the code in the other question.

Comment: Are you running `db.create_all()` after your generated classes are mapped?

Comment: @SuperShoot I just added that after the `type()` line and the table is still not created :/ I'm afraid I'm not getting `type` right... Is this the right way to do this?

Comment: Update your question with an example that we can copy and paste which reproduces the problem and we can try to work it out. Something like this (but include the example you come up with in the body of your question, not a link to a gist): https://gist.github.com/5uper5hoot/269932c383adb35ffe9086321f29ef98. Keep the example as short as possible with only enough detail to reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I managed to make it work (a test which creates the table and then checks if the table exists in the db passes! Although the print statement still prints the unexpected message).

I had to

- inherit from db.Model when defining `MyModel` in `app/my_model.py`.
- set `__abstract__ = True`.

The `type` command is now: `type(name.title(), (MyModel, db.Model), { '__tablename__' : name })`.

Now I am dealing with data insertion, since I have to find a way to specify to which table it should go. `Class xxx is not mapped` error... But that's another problem! (For which if anyone has any comments, will be more than thankful!).

Thanks to everyone who helped!